# Enforce order of JSON results

Tags: scala

I have very large result sets being imported from json. Each row of data in the json returns a very specific "column" order, that I would like to quickly iterate through. I'd prefer to avoid the overhead of checking/matching keys to process each piece of data. Unfortunately, scala.util.parsing.json puts these columns into a Map object, and when iterating through the Map, the order in which it iterates is random, and does not necessarily mirror the order of the columns in the JSON result. Is there a way to make the parser enforce the order of the JSON columns? One thought was if there is a way to tell the parser to use LinkedHashMap or ListMap as it is generating the objects. Would this be possible by extending the class or adding other traits? Do I have alternative options?

Comment: If your question includes the words "prefer to avoid the overhead", you probably want to avoid `scala.util.parsing.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider trying something like json4s.

It appears the JObject type has ordered fields.

https://github.com/json4s/json4s

Otherwise I would ask why you need them ordered?
You can always map.get by key.

Comment: json4s looks like it might be promising, although I need to find a way to enforce that all fields are parsed as strings (ex. long strings of numbers don't get parsed to double)

Comment: I am using the slick DB framework, and am dumping these values into a prepared statement. populating a prepared statement uses a numeric index to address each variable mapping. Given I could create a lookup table for each key name to its respective index, but I would rather not deal with the overhead of maintaining such a table, and also the processing power to perform that on each result row.

Comment: string fields are enclosed in double quotes in json. json4s will give you the correct type back.

Comment: careful with slick if you're using oracle or mssql as it costs a lot of money to go to prod

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over the json feed, and the numbers are not put into strings as they probably should be. With the stock parse, I can specify JSON.globalNumberParser = {input : String => input} to force everything to String. There may be a way to do this with json4s I might just have to do some more research.

Comment: ya you can just map over the values to convert to string with relative ease. not too sure if there is a better way with some type level ninjitsu and json4s. These libraries do some neat stuff - I contributed to jerkson a bit. https://github.com/jasongoodwin/jerkson

Answer (score 3):

**I'd strongly discourage you from relying on the order of key/value pairs.** JSON objects are [defined](http://www.json.org/) as:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Relying on the order will most likely introduce difficult bugs and incompatibility of your code. Trading correctness for speed is always a bad deal.

Instead I'd suggest to find a fast, correct parser. I've used [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) before, which is very fast, and can be well used with Scala. You [annotate](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/) an arbitrary class of yours and Jackson parses JSON into instances of the class. Then you can process these instances as native Java/Scala objects, which is both very fast and robust.

Comment: Jackson is a Java based library. There is a wrapper called Jerkson which was used by play! framework for a while. The project has been abandoned though so other libraries are getting more popular. Json4s can be backed by Jackson so I'd recommend using that in scala.

Comment: jackson has a scala module as well that makes the java library work with scala objects -> https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala